# Linear discriminant analysis and the "kernel trick"?

Tags: self-study, classification, kernel-trick

This is problem 12.10 in ["The Elements of Statistical Learning"](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/):

> Suppose you wish to carry
>   out a linear discriminant analysis
>   (two classes) using a vector of
>   transformations of the input variables
>   $h(x)$. Since $h(x)$ is
>   high-dimensional, you will use a
>   regularized within-class covariance
>   matrix $W_h + \gamma I$. Show that the
>   model can be estimated using only the
>   inner products  $K(x_i, x_{i'}) = \left < h(x_i), h(x_{i'}) \right >$.

How can I go about showing that regularized linear discriminant analysis can be estimated using only inner products, as in the "kernel trick" that is often used with SVM's?

Answer (score 2):

See the papers by Sebastian Mika and co-authors (I think this was the subject of Mika's PhD thesis).  The original paper is [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/NNSP.1999.788121) and for free [here](http://ml.cs.tu-berlin.de/publications/MikRaeWesSchMue99.pdf).